# "npm i" displays broken output ("Enter passphrase for key...") and spinner, and entering passphrase does nothing

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ssh, npm

This is on Ubuntu 16.04. Terminal emulator is Konsole 15.12.3. Node.js is 4.8.2, installed as described [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

What happens:

```
$ npm i
npm WARN package.json my-proj@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json my-proj@0.1.0 No license field.
-nter passphrase for key '/home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa': /
```

That's how it displays it, with the duplication, with the (non-spinning) `/` at the end and with the (spinning) `-` instead of the `E` in `Enter`.

If I just press enter at this point, I get errors such as `Permission denied (publickey).` - understandable, as I haven't entered my passphrase.

If I enter my passphrase instead (while the cursor is at the spinner, and nothing visibly changes while typing), and *then* press enter, I get one more row of:

```
-nter passphrase for key '/home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa': \
```

... and nothing else happens. If I then press enter again, I get messages such as `Permission denied (publickey).` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague gave me the solution: use a key that has no passphrase.

Comment: Or use ssh-agent or similar, which would be more secure.